# How can I update an object in a list using user selected index

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I am trying to update an object in a list with a user selected index. I want to change the form title when the method is called and fill the textboxes with items from the selected object. I want to disable the studentname and studentID boxes so that the only text that can be updated are the grades. How do I use the index input to refer to the object in the list and change the specific components of the object?

```
namespace C03
{
    public partial class frmAddStudent : Form
    {
        public frmAddStudent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Student student = null;

        public Student GetNewStudent()
        {
            this.ShowDialog();
            return student;
        }

        public void UpdateStudent(int i)
        {
            this.Text = "Update Student Information";
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace C03
{
    public partial class frmStudentScores : Form
    {
        public frmStudentScores()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private List<Student> students = null;

        private void frmStudentScores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            students = StudentDB.GetStudent();
            if (students.Count==0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No students on file at this time");
            }
            else
            {
                FillStudentListBox();
            }
        }

        private void FillStudentListBox()
        {
            lstStudentsScores.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Student s in students)
            {
                lstStudentsScores.Items.Add(s.DisplayStudInfo(4));
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmAddStudent addStudent = new frmAddStudent();
            Student student = addStudent.GetNewStudent();
            if (student != null)
            {
                students.Add(student);
                StudentDB.SaveStudents(students);

                FillStudentListBox();
            }
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = lstStudentsScores.SelectedIndex;
            if (i != -1)
            {
                Student student = (Student)students[i];
                string message = "Are you sure you want to delete " + student.DisplayStudInfo();
                DialogResult button = MessageBox.Show(message, "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (button == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    students.Remove(student);
                    StudentDB.SaveStudents(students);
                    FillStudentListBox();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("please select a student.");
                    lstStudentsScores.Focus();
                    lstStudentsScores.SelectedIndex = lstStudentsScores.Items.Count - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define the word trouble

Comment: Hi @mason, Welcome to stackoverflow. When asking questions please be clear. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @viveknuna im not sure how to do what i described